# Running coffescript files with gulp-express

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

I am creating an API in expressJS, and I want to reload the server each time a file is changed

I tried

```
gulp.task('server', function () {

 // Start the server at the beginning of the task
    server.run({
        file: 'server.coffee'
    });

    // Restart the server when file changes
    gulp.watch(['*coffee'], server.notify);

});
```

But it fails because it thinks the coffee file is a javascript file, and the returns syntax errors

Comment: Have you tried using the [gulp-coffee package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-coffee) it should handle this nicely

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to let gulp-express run coffee-script directly. So, I changed gulpfile.js as follows.

```
 gulp.task('server', function () {
    server.run({
        file: 'app.js'
    });
    :

 });
```

And, I created a new app.js.

```
require('coffee-script/register');
require('./server')
```